# Obter todas classes que implementam a ClassMapping<>

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

```
List<Type> entityMappings = new List<Type>();
IEnumerable<Type> allTypesInThisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

foreach (Type type in allTypesInThisAssembly)
{
    if (type.GetInterface(typeof(ClassMapping<>).Name.ToString()) != null)
    {
        entityMappings.Add(type);
    }
}
```

Tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Explique melhor o seu problema, o que exatamente você está querendo fazer e por que?

Comment: desculpa a demora pra responder. Basicamente fazer a configuração para adicionar um singleton do NHibernate, e tava tendo problema no addMapping, e pra isso, precisava que o NHibernate tivesse uma classe de exemplo.  que no Exemplo do meu codigo usei o Aluno Map. Mas depois de muita pesquisa, consegui resolver.

Comment: Então., era isso que você deveria ter escrito em sua pergunta....

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
 services.AddSingleton<ISessionFactory>((serviceProvider) =>
        {
            var settings = configuration.GetSection("NHibernateConfig")
                                    .GetChildren()
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

            var nhConfiguration = new Configuration();
            nhConfiguration.AddProperties(settings);

            var mapper = new ModelMapper();

            mapper.AddMappings(typeof(AlunoMap).Assembly.ExportedTypes);
            HbmMapping mappings = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
            
            mappings.autoimport = false;
            nhConfiguration.AddMapping(mappings);

            return nhConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
        });
```